# Java Split strings on "." and "?"

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String testStr = "Test test. Test 2. Test3?";
    String[] newStr = testStr.split(".?");
    System.out.print(newStr[0]);
}
```

I get an Array Index Out of Bounds exception running this, and the length of newStr is 0. I want to break the sentence up into tokens on "." and "?". What error am I making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as a parameter to split. `.` and `?` have special meaning in regular expressions.

You can use character class to split on either of them:

```
testStr.split("[.?]");
```

Inside a character class you don't need to escape them, as special characters lose meaning inside character class.

If you use it with normal pipe `|`, you need to escape it: -

```
testStr.split("\\.|\\?");
```

**UPDATE**: - If you want to preserve your delimiters:

```
testStr.split("(?<=[.?])")
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to preserve the period and question marks in the tokens?

Answer (score 4):

You must escape those characters. Use `"\\."` and `"\\?"`. This is because `String#split` receives a regular expression, and both characters are special characters in regex.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape `.` and `?`. Use :

```
String[] newStr = testStr.split("\\.|\\?");
```

Comment: I didn't know the parentheses to group the "a or b" in a regex were optional